# Set div height to fit container with overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a two column div in a modal with overflow.

The left div is taller than the right div and causes overflow, and the right div has a slightly darker background color.

If I set right div `height` to 100%, or set the `top` and `bottom` to 0, then it only fills to the hight of the modal, so if you scroll down to see contend in the left div, then the background color of the overflow in the right goes to default.

[image]

How can I get that grey background to fill the entire height of the modal?  I can't set a specific height for the column divs.

edit: [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lvp3n5h/)

Comment: Maybe you should create a jsfiddle to demonstrate how it is done in detail. However, why don't you try using display: table for the holder and display: table-cell for the columns?

Comment: Okay, working on a fiddle now.

Comment: Why people are voting to close this as off topic?  It's a specific coding question.  Also, I added a JS fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSS table-layout](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/):

```
.two-column {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
.right-column {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lvp3n5h/1/

```css
.modal {
    display: table; 
}

.two-column {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}

.left-column {
    height: 5000px; /* This is actually dynamic in my case */
}

.right-column {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
    <div class="two-column left-column">Stuff</div>
    <div class="two-column right-column">I wish this div would keep a gray background color even after scrolling.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 for this with display flex for the parent, to fit the height of the children to parent's height.

- Example: https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/
- Reliable documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate and assign the height using javascript.

If you want to do it using css only:

you can use

```
display:table-cell;
```

see below link for reference:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45smnvee/)

and if your left panel will always going to remain the larger one then you can also use the following trick:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhe56821/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Javascript` or `Jquery` to set height of `right div` equal to `left div` when the page already loaded.

If you don't want to use Javascript or Jquery, I have a trick for your page like this:

- Wrap two `div` inside a `wrap div` then set `background-color` darker to it.
- The `left div` set `background-color` same as the modal.
- The `right div` is not set `background-color` => It looks like darker background same as `wrap div`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using padding on the right div or you can use 
 tags to fill the space. Although it isn't the perfect coding practice but always does the trick